# How Google TalkBack service draws Rectangle over buttons/texts/images/etc.?

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas, ondraw, accessibilityservice

Before you start typing I would say that you were going to write down the documentation of `AccessibilityService`, `AccessibilityNodeInfo`, etc.

I've implemented my `AccessibilityService` correctly and I am even getting the `AccessibilityEvent`-s correctly.

I am only concerned about how to draw Rectangle around the view by user's clicks.

What I have done so far regarding to this:

- Created custom view class which implemented `ViewGroup`
- I added that `CustomView` (class I wrote) as a `View` with `WindowManager`, byt calling `.addView()` method
- I am drawing Rectangle on `Canvas` by calling `canvas.drawRect()` from `onDraw()` overloaded method
- When adding view on the screen I use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` flag and `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY` type for parameters to pass into `.addView()` method

You may wonder what's the problem here..

Here They are:

1. When adding new `CustomView` with `WindowManager` service, the whole new `View` covers the screen and other buttons are not accessible. ( I literally can't click anything except the newly added layer, I think it's getting drawn on top of everything and everything becomes unclickable)
2. adding custom view as a layer instead of drawing directly around some View, causes (or not, I don't know exactly) `event.source.getBoundsInScreen(rect)` in `onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent)` to store wrong directions of button clicked by user. (When I draw the same Rectangle with `canvas.drawRect(rect, mpaint)` the rectangle isn't show exactly around the view, some coordinates are mistaken)

I *want* to make my `AccessibilityService` draw Rectangle like [Google TalkBack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_TalkBack) does it.

The **Google TalkBack** draws ***PERFECT*** Rectangle around the View, but mine doesn't, unfortunately.

- Here are the screenshots of my app drawing the rectangle: (clicked on '9')

[image: mine screen]

- Here is the screenshot of **Google TalkBack** clicking '9' button:

[image: talkbacks screen]

Thanks.

Comment: Can't really help with the technical aspects of what you're doing, but that rect looks like it's offset by exactly half the view height - you sure you're not just miscalculating the coordinates?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! here is the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/tb2s807) of `onDraw`. I have added `- this.rectToDraw.height() / 2` when calculating coordinates, but this doesn't worked for another application :/ here is the [screenshot](https://ibb.co/kyPMwJr) as well. weird

Comment: but adding `- this.rectToDraw.height() / 2` worked like a charm on calculator. The rectangle is shown correctly there.. lmao.. I think I would need to check `packageName` and make another subtraction of `- this.rectToDraw.height() / 2` if the another package is shown instead calculator.

Comment: Where are you getting ``rectToDraw`` from? Like I said I don't know anything about the accessibility stuff you're working with, but it looks like what you're doing is basically working, it's just got that extremely suspicious 50% offset thing going on. Are you taking padding into account when you work out the width/height/x and y offsets? That image with the purple buttons looks like they have vertical padding or margins, but the calculator buttons don't

Comment: I get rectToDraw from `onAccessibilityEvent` where it can provide me `event.source.getBoundsInScreen(rectangle)` and `rectangle` will contain my `Rect` object. I understand what you are saying, that maybe the purple buttons have paddings and stuff, but why **Google TalkBack** can draw rectangle as well as it's drawing in Calculator then? :/ I think something more 200 IQ going on with TalkBack then just getting `getBoundsInScreen` and drawing that rectangle. I'll double check the coordinates calculating still.

Comment: So you basically have a full-screen view, and you're getting the screen coordinates of the button being pressed, and you're drawing them straight onto your full-screen view? (Like I said, not familiar with this!) If that's what's happening then it should just work, which makes me wonder if your view is offset, so its top ``0`` coordinate isn't where the screen's top ``0`` coordinate is? When you add your view, do you have to account for things like the toolbar, the system bar etc, maybe add a flag to be placed over them instead of below? Try drawing a rect starting at (0,0) and see where it is

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232424/discussion-between-nikoloz-chitashvili-and-cactustictacs).

Comment: Did you find a workaround in the end?

Comment: @timr, hey, sorry for late response. So, basically workaround was the thing I've already done. Just draw the rectangle, but other screen is becoming unresponsive. It's up to you if this is ok for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic is that TalkBack *doesn't* draw the box. It's actually drawn in the app process. There's code in ViewRootImpl that handles it. This functionality can only be used when Touch Exploration is enabled, which make it unusable for anything not interested in a user experience very similar to TalkBack's.

Anticipating the follow-up, no we don't plan to open this up. The overlay, while offsets are always fiddly, is a much more scalable approach to helping services highlight content.

Comment: So, as I understand the answer, it's practically impossible for me to draw the Rectangle around the view like **TalkBack** does it? That's so unfortunate. I'll try to find some solutions within my case then.

Comment: I found https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction#ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN

Comment: Can this be used to draw the green box on the requested NodeInfo?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the alignment's improved if you subtract the status bar height

```
private void updateBounds(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo) {
  nodeInfo.getBoundsInScreen(mBoundsRect);
  mBoundsRect.top -= getStatusBarHeight();
  mBoundsRect.bottom -= getStatusBarHeight();
}

private int getStatusBarHeight() {
  WindowInsets insets = mWindowManager.getCurrentWindowMetrics().getWindowInsets();
  WindowInsetsCompat windowInsets = WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(insets);
  return windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars()).top;
}
```

But I similarly saw the bounds were inconsistent and whether the offset was needed changed on the app and screen size of the device.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, I no longer support this project, but thank you for your help!